# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: previous solution doesn't work in Xcode 12.5.1

Tags: xcode, flutter, arm64

I am working on a flutter project. My project includes tflite and amplify packages. it works fine with android but whenever I try to build it in Xcode I am getting this following errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

"*OBJC_CLASS*$_FlutterStandardTypedData", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in tflite(TflitePlugin.o)
enter code here

"_FlutterMethodNotImplemented", referenced from:
-[TflitePlugin handleMethodCall:result:] in tflite(TflitePlugin.o)

"*OBJC_CLASS*$_FlutterMethodChannel", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in tflite(TflitePlugin.o)

"*OBJC_METACLASS*$_FlutterAppDelegate", referenced from:
*OBJC_METACLASS*$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o

"*OBJC_CLASS*$_FlutterAppDelegate", referenced from:
*OBJC_CLASS*$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please help me with this. I have been stuck with this issue for more than a week now. Thank you.

I have added a snippet from Xcode which shows the current settings for Architectures. There are past suggestions to add arm64 as a Valid architectures. However, as you see there is no option for that. I added arm64 in excluded architectures as shown in the picture. It didn't work for me.

[image: Picture for better understanding]